# Multiple CSS selectors for a set of properties

Tags: html, css

How do I select multiple elements for a set of CSS properties?

For example how do I do this correctly?:

```
.facebook:hover,twitter:hover {
    padding-left: 50px;
    opacity: 1.0;
    -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .7s ease;
    -o-transition: all .7s ease;
    transition: all .7s ease;
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}
```

Comment: you have missed the dot (.) in front of twitter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible. You're only lacking the `.` before twitter:

```
.facebook:hover,
.twitter:hover {
  padding-left: 50px;
  opacity: 1.0;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .7s ease;
  -o-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all .7s ease;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **dot (.)** before twitter class.

```
.facebook:hover, .twitter:hover {
padding-left: 50px;
opacity: 1.0;
-webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
-moz-transition: all .7s ease;
-ms-transition: all .7s ease;
-o-transition: all .7s ease;
transition: all .7s ease;
border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}
```